# How to limit the number of concurrent threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading, threadpool

In `VIDEO_URL`, there are thousands of videos to be downloaded. I want to use threads to do the job, but limit to at most ten threads at a time. How could I rewrite the following code to get it?

```
VIDEO_URL.each do | video |
  @workers << Thread.new{dl_video(video)}
end
@workers.each { |t| t.join }
```

## Update

The gem **thread pool** seems not to be blocked after the work threads more than 10,  Is the I/O block to make the thread pool has no effect ?

If I download videos without threadpool, it works well.

But if I download videos with threadpool, the video won't be download, the main thread  supposed to be  block when there are 10 workers , but it didn't.
( Every video should at least has 1 minute to download )

```
MAX_WORKERS = 10
@pool = Thread.pool(MAX_WORKERS)

def dl_video(video)
  File.open(video["title"], "wb") do |saved_file|
    @pool.process{
      saved_file.write open(video["link"], :allow_redirections => :safe).read
      # saved_file.write(HTTParty.get(video["link"]).parsed_response)
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to implement is a frequently used pattern, and it is called *thread pool*.

I haven't tried it, but perhaps [threadpool](https://github.com/meh/ruby-threadpool) gem or something similar is worth looking into:

```
require "threadpool"

pool = ThreadPool.new(10)
VIDEO_URL.each{|video| pool.process{dl_video(video)}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the gem **threadpool** seems not to be blocked after the work threads more than 10,  Is the I/O block to make the thread pool has no effect ?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called a thread pool. There is an [extension](https://github.com/meh/ruby-thread) for Ruby's threads, which includes this functionality.

Untested snippet directly adapted from the libraries example:

```
require 'thread/pool'

# Create thread pool with up to 10 simultaneous running threads 
pool = Thread.pool(10)

VIDEO_URL.each do | video |
  # Add each download task the the thread pool
  pool.process do 
    dl_video(video)
  end
end

# Block and wait for the thread pool to run out of tasks
pool.shutdown
```

Comment: @ibr The gem **thread pool** seems not to be blocked after the work threads more than 10,  Is the I/O block to make the thread pool has no effect ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question.

Comment: hi I updated my description, I mean the if I put the task in the threadpool the video wont be download

Comment: I think you are using the gem sawa mentioned, and not the one i did. I've tested the code in my reply and `pool.shutdown` blocks fine.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution (without involving any new gems) would be to initiate 10 threads that `pop` and process the first URL in your array.

```
[].tap do |threads|
  urls = VIDEO_URLS.clone
  semaphore = Mutex.new
  number_of_threads = 10

  number_of_threads.times do
    threads << Thread.new do
      until urls.empty?        
        url = semaphore.synchronize { urls.pop }
        download_video(url)
      end
    end
  end
end.each(&:join)
```

Another solution could be to split your array into different slices (10 or less); there are different ways you can do this. Afterwards, each thread could process each slice. The code might be longer overall but you would get rid of `Mutex`, if you want.

```
[].tap do |threads|
  slices # split VIDEO_URLS into required slices. leave this up to you.
  slices.each do |urls|
    threads << Thread.new do
      urls.each { |url| download_video(url) }
    end
  end
end.each(&:join)
```

Comment: Your first example is a very minimal thread pool implementation  :-)

Comment: Yeah. Basically, the same thing as a thread-pool but without adding any extra gems. Edit: I notice the mistake in my post. It said "without involving threadpools" when it should've been "without involving threadpool-gems". Corrected. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [each_slice](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice).

```
VIDEO_URL.each_slice(10) do | batch |
    batch.each do |video|
        @workers << Thread.new{dl_video(video)}
    end
    @workers.each { |t| t.join }
    @workers = []
end
```

Comment: This approach will create up to ten simultaneous downloads, wait for all ten to finish, then create up to  new threads, wait for them to finish and so on. That might not be optimal :)

Comment: I agree with you, it is not the nicest way.